# Shell script permission denied despite +x flag

Tags: permissions, bash, scripting, shell

This is an odd one, it only happens on one server (shared hosting, so I have limited access to configuration and logs), but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a shell script which runs some app's deployment. The file has a +x flag, but I can't run it by simply calling its name from shell, I get an "access denied" error. Invoking bash with the filename as an arguments works like a charm. It looks something like that:

```
[someuser@someserver:~] $cat test.sh
echo "hooray!"
[someuser@someserver:~] $chmod +x test.sh
[someuser@someserver:~] $ls -l test.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 someuser someuser 14 Oct  8 11:27 test.sh
[someuser@someserver:~] $./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
[someuser@someserver:~] $bash test.sh
hooray!
```

Adding a `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning doesn't help. I also tried from other shell (default is bash, tried in sh), same thing happened.

This is not that big of a problem, but it's baffling for me. What could be the cause?

Comment: The `#!` line in the beginning of a script is mandatory. If you leave it out, the kernel will refuse to run the script. Some shells have a workaround, which will allow them to run the script anyway. However those workarounds will cause the script to behave differently depending on how it was called and break completely if it wasn't called from a shell with a workaround. For those reasons you should never rely on those workarounds and instead include a correctly formatted `#!` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because of the "noexec" mount option for the folder your script is in.
You may try to check that by this command

```
mount | grep `df -P /path/to/folder/with/script | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

Comment: How do I verify this?

Comment: Added command to my answer. You may have look at /etc/fstab. According to your example you are in a home directory, so you'll see a `/home` mountpoint. There should be `noexec` directive at the end of mountpoint's options.

Comment: As I said this is a shared hosting, so for security reasons there's not much I can do. Mount command is not available to me, `/etc/fstab` doesn't exist (or that's what it looks like from my perspective). Some interesting config...

Comment: Sorry, missed the `shared hosting` bit. Then you have nothing to do as your shared hosting provider mounted home directories with the noexec option for security reasons.